# Error 0xC0C01B4C on Debatching Envelope in Simple Orchestration

Tags: biztalk

We have a simple Envelope XML that I am trying to debatch using a custom pipeline on the receive side of a HTTP Send/Receive port . BizTalk will pass through the first set in the envelope but we get the error 0xC0C01B4C (Zombie) for all that follow. For testing purposes I am sending the results of the receive out to a folder in file format. I am hoping someone out there has seen this before as I have been trying many different ways to resolve this issue.

this is the Envelope Message

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?> 
<xs:schema xmlns="http://CC.Schemas.ADDR.ADDR_IDs_Envelope" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" xmlns:ids="http://CC.Schemas.ADDR.ADDR_IDs" targetNamespace="http://CC.Schemas.ADDR.ADDR_IDs_Envelope" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:import schemaLocation=".\ADDR_IDs.xsd" namespace="http://CC.Schemas.ADDR.ADDR_IDs" /> 
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>
            <b:schemaInfo is_envelope="yes" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" /> 
            <b:references>
                <b:reference targetNamespace="http://CC.Schemas.ADDR.ADDR_IDs" /> 
            </b:references>
        </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:element name="ADDR_IDs_Envelope">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
                <b:recordInfo body_xpath="/*[local-name()='ADDR_IDs_Envelope' and namespace-uri()='http://CC.Schemas.ADDR.ADDR_IDs_Envelope']/*[local-name()='Messages' and namespace-uri()='']" /> 
            </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Messages">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="ids:ADDR_IDs" /> 
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Details ID's Schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?> 
<xs:schema xmlns="http://CC.Schemas.ADDR.ADDR_IDs" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" targetNamespace="http://CC.Schemas.ADDR.ADDR_IDs" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="ADDR_IDs">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="TransactionID" type="xs:string" /> 
                <xs:element name="JWID" type="xs:positiveInteger" /> 
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

[image: Orchestration]

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply your Orchestration is missing a loop where it listens for the next message for the same Correlation.  So after processing the first message it will just exit leaving the others unprocessed.

The concept you need is called a sequential convoy.  You need to have another Receive Shape (which has the Following Correlation Sets you initialised on the first Receive Shape as an Initializing Correlation Sets) inside a loop as well as a way of exiting the loop, e.g. below is where there is a time limit to wait for exiting the loop.  You need to get this exit condition correct otherwise there is still the chance of a zombie.

[image]

Comment: I guess I mistakenly thought that debatching the envelope which is what is received back would automatically do that without loops. I will set as you have indicated thanks for the help

Comment: @JWall  The debatching is probably happening in the Receive Location.  If you want to debatch a message in an Orchestration you need to either execute the pipeline in the Orchestration or use XSLT, but that will still require a loop to get the next message.

Comment: Thanks I think I saw some examples of using the pipeline in an orchestration so I might look at that option first. Much appreciated

Comment: I have been trying to get this working with Orchestration Pipeline option and I believe I have everything set properly but inside my Call to the Pipeline I am getting the following error  have been trying to find the issue both the Detail and the Envelope are defined within the pipeline "Shape name: CallPipeline
Inner exception: There was a failure executing pipeline "CC.Orchestrations.ReceiveAndDebatch". Error details: "Document type "http://CC.Schemas.ADDR.ADDR_IDs#ADDR_IDs" does not match any of the given schemas. ".

Comment: @JWall Then the schema you have specified in the pipeline and the message's don't match.

Comment: This same pipeline worked outside of the orchestration without any issues other then my initial problem of needing loop. Also I tried setting the receive schema from the http request to both the envelope and also the detail schema same issue. With the setting of detail as my schema I know the de-batching is happening before the pipeline call in my orchestration. I used the pipeline code I had found online and will post here to see if perhaps I need to change something there. Thanks for the help as I would like to get this working by this method if possible

Comment: When I test http request with postman I receive back the envelope I expect.<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ADDR_IDs_Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://CC.Schemas.ADDR.ADDR_IDs_Envelope">
    <Messages xmlns="">
        <ADDR_IDs xmlns="http://CCD.Schemas.ADDR.ADDR_IDs">
            <TransactionID xmlns="">EMPTY</TransactionID>
        </ADDR_IDs>
    </Messages>
</ADDR_IDs_Envelope>

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to post an update on this problem I had as I decided to use the Orchestration Pipeline Method and had schema issues. To fix this I had to

## 1 - Change my receive message and port to System.Xml.XmlDocument message type instead of setting this to my schema. You also have to set the receive pipeline to PassTrhuReceive instead of XML Transmit. Since XML Transmit pipeline will debatch automatically. This allows my loop to process the debatching in the Orchestration as I wanted. I was using a Send/Recieve http port and was able to get this working

One Gotcha on this is you have to use a Scope with the Orchestration Pipeline method so it will not send the message out as I intended one at a time in order.

In one of my orchestrations I had to also use the sequential convoy so that I could process the Envelope message in order one at a time not all of them needed this so the first method worked great at fixing the Zombie message problem I had. Since I already had this operation split in two I ended up saving the Envelope to a folder then picking it up and processing it through sequential convoy.

Everything is working as intended now